# "should" ---- Alternative meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This excerpt is from Chapter XIV of Uncle Tom's Cabin ( in case the full text is required: http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Harriet_Beecher_Stowe/Uncle_Toms_Cabin/Evangeline_p5.html)

> Tom was standing just under her on the lower deck, as she fell. He saw her strike the water, and sink, and was after her in a moment. A broad-chested, strong-armed fellow, it was nothing for him to keep afloat in the water, till, in a moment or two the child rose to the surface, and he caught her in his arms, and, swimming with her to the boat-side, handed her up, all dripping, to the grasp of hundreds of hands, which, as if they had all belonged to one man, were stretched eagerly out to receive her. A few moments more, and her father bore her, dripping and senseless, to the ladies' cabin, where, as is usual in cases of the kind, there ensued a very well-meaning and kind-hearted strife among the female occupants generally, as to who **should** do the most things to make a disturbance, and to hinder her recovery in every way possible.

Pardon me, but "should" here sounds odd as it does not mean that as in "You should go to school today".

Comment: It means "ought to."

Comment: -1 no research indicated.  What research have you done? Which dictionaries have you checked? What is it about definitions and examples of usage that leave you confused? Alternative meaning to what?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place; *should* has its usual meaning here. It's talking about a situation where people are taking the patient's temperature, asking if they're ok, changing their clothes, injecting them with medicine and so on, unfortunately all tending to disrupt the patient's sleep.

Comment: @Lawrence I agree that without the last half sentence " to hinder her recovery in every way possible", your explanation makes perfect sense. But why would kind-hearted female occupants "should" go out of their way for every means to hinder the girl's recovery? It runs counter to their good meaning, doesn't it?

Comment: It's probably to inject a little light-hearted feel to the piece.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Stowe is saying that the crowd around the poor girl is doing everything BUT what they should; namely, let her recover by resting, for example. There is a tinge of irony here. Stowe is not saying the crowd SHOULD do those things; rather, that they should not. A very simple form of irony. Don

Answer (score 0):

These days a writer would probably put "who *could* do the most things...". Technically, however, 'a competition as to who could do the most' refers only to who has the ability; who actually does most is decided by a competition as to who should do the most. It appears that writing was more recise in th 19th century.

Answer (score -1):

Actually *should* here does mean the same as in "You should go to school today", even though it's more convoluted.

*… who should… * is a question but the answer will be *… she should (who is best qualified according to the terms in the passage…)*

Comment: Hey Robbie, but it does not match the whole context if you could kindly take a closer look at the passage, in that "who is best qualified to disturb the girl and hinder her recovery." It makes more sense to me  to interpret it as "who would disturb the girl and hinder her recovery."

Comment: *who is best qualified…* matches the context perfectly.

*Would* suggests no real question of qualification for the task. The choice might as well be made by the toss of a coin. *Would* carries no sense of *strife*, however well-meaning or kind-hearted.

*Should*, here, can’t mean *has a duty to*. It almost means *deserves to*; whether through real qualifications or just by blacking the most eyes in a physical striving matters not.

Try, ie, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=should&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=should&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j69i61.1542j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: My understanding of the passage agrees with Shun's. It does not seem to be about qualifications for making trouble.

Comment: Thanks. There are senses in which *should* and *would* share a meaning; not this.

*who should* could be decided by straws among quaified pickers.

aparente001’s *ought to* seems to show not just a choice but a necessary reason for it.

Who thinks It doesn’t seem to be about qualifications for trouble, or that it makes more sense as *who would disturb the girl and hinder her recovery…* is welcome to take it up with Beecher Stowe or any dictionary.

Whatever, who out there thinks any modern publisher would have allowed Harriet to get away with a passage like that?